# "System.Byte[]" is being returned instead of the actual data

Tags: c#

This code is intended to calculate and print the MD5 hash of a file on my desktop. However, on compilation all that is written to the console window is "System.Byte[]" Putting a ToString() didn't resolve the issue either.

```
MD5 a = MD5.Create();
Console.Write(a.ComputeHash(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\TTDDWW\Desktop\putty.exe")));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `Console.Write` relies on the `Object.ToString` method to make a string representation of an object. `Array` does not override this method, therefore for arrays it returns the type name - that's the default implementation. To make a hex representation of a byte array, use `BitConverter.ToString`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains things perfectly!

Comment: The [MSDN page of the MD5 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) has an example that shows exactly what you want to do, actualy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BitConverter` to create a hex string out of the `byte[]` array:

```
MD5 a = MD5.Create();
byte[] hash = a.ComputeHash(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\TTDDWW\Desktop\putty.exe"));
string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
Console.Write(hexString);
```

`BitConverter.ToString()` gives you a representation of the form `AA-AA-AA-AA` so you have to remove the hyphens and make the string lowercase to get the common MD5 hex string.

Comment: Or you can use `.ToString("x2")` on the bytes ;)