# How can I create a file and insert byte in this file in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

My issue is when I create this controller :

```
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
public IActionResult CreateFile(string word){
    word = "test";

    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(word);

    var txtBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    txtBuilder.Append(b);
    var txtContent = txtBuilder.ToString();
    var txtStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtContent));

    return File(txtStream,"text/plain","license.dat");
}
```

When I try this request on swagger, it allow me to download a file. When I download the file the content is :

> System.Byte[]

But when I test this on swagger :

```
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
public IActionResult CreateFile(string word){
    word = "test";

    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(word);

    return BadRequest(b);
}
```

the result of b is :

> dGVzdA==

I don't want to see `test` or `System.Byte[]` inside the created file I want to see the result of b on the created file.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you expect to see in the file? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or why you're converting back and forth between binary and text.

Comment: Should check that "text/plain"

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "binary data"? Everything that goes across the wire is binary in the end. What exact bytes do you expect to be in that `MemoryStream`? 4 bytes, one for each character? Or some textual representation (e.g. in hex)?

Comment: @JonSkeet I update my ticket.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense to me - because the value of `word` is `"test"`. What you've claimed to be the result is the base64-encoded version of the ASCII-encoded bytes of "test". Where are you seeing that result? Please edit your question to make it a lot clearer - while it's unclear, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: @bradbury9 if I remove "text/plain" I have this error : "The header contains invalid values at index 0: 'license.dat'"

Comment: @user10863293, if you want to have binary data, then you need to specify the right content-type. In your example there is "text/plain".

Comment: @JonSkeet I edit.

Comment: When you do `txtBuilder.Append(b);` the base `object.ToString()` of `byte[]` is appended. You can't append bytes to string unless you re-encode them in some way.

Comment: It's still not clear where you're seeing that result. *Something* is converting that information into base64, and it's not clear whether you *want* base64 data or not. If your data is just text to start with, why aren't you just using `File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(word), "text/plain", "license.dat")`?

Comment: @JonSkeet because when I do that I can't download my file.
and if I do that File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(word), "application/octet-stream", "license.dat"), my file is empty.

Comment: It looks written much complex than possible.

Comment: @user10863293: That suggests the way you're downloading the file may be broken, but we can't see that...

Comment: Although I've got the solution, I still have absolutelly no idea, how he could get base64 string converted from the Byte Array. I am getting always only the string "System.Byte[]" returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got you.

This is what you want:

```
[HttpGet("CreateFile")]
public IActionResult CreateFile(string word)
{
    word = "test";

    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(word);
    string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b);
    b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64);
    var txtStream = new MemoryStream(b);

    return File(txtStream, "text/plain", "license.dat");
}
```

Comment: Its just me or this has nothing to do with "_I_ _want_ _to_ _have_ _bynary_ _data_ _in_ _the_ _file_" yet it is useful to OP? The OP coments in the question were missleading

Comment: @bradbury9 yep, you are right. But it doesn't matter anymore. It's cleared already.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following answer. You should have a right solution there: [Returning CSV from .NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977036/2487565)

TL;DR: Use FileResult instead of IActionResult or set the Content-Disposition header.

Another very good article: [How to Return Files From Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-files-from-web-api/)

Explanation about: System.Byte[]

I guess, since you've set the content-type to "text/plain" there is .ToString() convertion somewhere. Look at the first conneto to this question. ["System.Byte[]" is being returned instead of the actual data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106426/system-byte-is-being-returned-instead-of-the-actual-data)

> Array does not override this method, therefore for arrays it returns the type name - that's the default implementation.

Comment: I try but nothing work for me :/

Comment: @user10863293 check my answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847016/2487565.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what do you mean with the result "dGVzdA=="

But this simple works:

```
[HttpGet("CreateFile")]
public IActionResult CreateFile(string word)
{
    word = "test";

    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(word);
    var txtStream = new MemoryStream(b);

    return File(txtStream, "text/plain", "license.dat");
}
```

I am getting a file with "test" inside.

But you should better use

```
public FileResult CreateFile(string word)
```

And, Of cource, you can use UTF8 instead of ASCII

```
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(word);
```

Comment: Of cource, you can use UTF8 instead of ASCII

Comment: Yes But I don't want to have a file with test inside.
When I do a Console.WriteLine of Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(word) I have this result on my api dGVzdA==

I also want to have the same result inside my file when it will be created.

Comment: @user10863293. What do you want to have instead of "test"?
If you want to have text from the _word_ parameter, then delete the line word = "test";

Comment: @user10863293: Then you need to clarify what you *do* want. It's really, really unclear what you want, how you're downloading the file etc.